# Android: Pulling data from a server?

Tags: android, sql-server, json, client

I'm a newbie when it comes to client/server apps but I have an idea for an app but need a few ideas on how to implement it.  I want users to be able to submit say a post and the server would store it. Other users will be able to also submit posts...the posts will then be able to be viewed as a list updated from the server.  What is the best way to ndo this with android? JSON? SQL? What have you found easy? Thanks any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a server component with your app-specific services, such as creating a post, retrieving all posts, etc. JSON is a simple and good choice.

Use `DefaultHttpClient` or `AndroidHttpClient` for communicating with your server via HTTP:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/package-summary.html

Use the `org.json` package to create requests and parse responses:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

These packages and classes are basically available on all Android devices, and they are fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

- [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) or [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) for communication
- [Android JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) library or for large data [Jackson Streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi)
- [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)
- [C2DM](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/android/c2dm/index.html) to push messages or [Deacon project](http://deacon.daverea.com/) for custom server

Everything is built into Android SDK except [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [Deacon](http://deacon.daverea.com/)